# If I use my own plugin, does that make me a second party?

Tags: discussion, fun

This question occurred to me after reading the "Third Party tools for the Trilogy" thread a while back. If I write what would normally be a third party tool, and use that tool myself ... does that mean to me it's a second party tool?

Comment: You have disgraced the `[always-friday-in-iceland]` tag with your non-humorous question.

Comment: @Earlz: Well it was supposed to be funny. Removed the tag. Happy now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer is the first party, the enduser is the second party, any code/API used in the developer's product, but not developed by the developer is third party.

In your particular case, it's imo the first party tool.

Comment: Hmm...Is this bit about 2nd person being the end user right? I've always though 3rd party came from the gramatical term 3rd person ( [Wikipedia - Gramatical person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person) ). 1st person being "I". 3rd person is "He/She/They". I would say that 1st party is anything you write (regardless of it's format or style of use). 3rd party is written by anyone else. End users don't come into it. Am I wrong? I agree with your final statement though - What Billy is talking about is just simple a 1st party tool.

Comment: What if the first part of the second party is the second part of the first party? Then-a you got something! */Chico Marx*

Comment: @Simon: Endusers indeed doesn't write code.

Comment: @Simon P Stevens: Second (gramatical) person is the person actually reading. First person is the character in the story, second person is the reader, third person is anyone else (i.e. a narrator)

Comment: @Billy. Ahh, interesting, well then I suppose that would make the second person the end user. Does kind of make sense.

Comment: @Billy: no, Simon's right.  it's only "first person" if the character is narrating (because the story goes *"I did this, I did that"*).  it's "third person" when someone else is narrating (*"he did this, she did that"*).  very very rarely is it "second person" (*"you did this, you did that"*).  (Italo Calvino anyone?)

Answer (score 1):

First and third-party plugins are linguistically based off the narrative concept of the first, second and third person perspective, i.e. *I*, *you*, and *they*.

So yes, if you are not a first-party producer of the tool, you wrote the tool and are using the tool. For you that is a second-party tool.

Source: Personal assumptions and being an English major as well as developer.

Comment: ([We *have* different **kinds** of ***emphasis*** here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). There is no need for weird encodings.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Regardless of who uses it, methinks it would be a first-party tool.

And if @Earlz reads this, let it be known that I resisted mentioning a meme :)

Comment: Of course, you couldn't resist mentioning that you resisted mentioning a meme.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use my own plugin, does that make me a second party?

No, I'm pretty sure it does not. I've actually been investigating this for a while... turns out that even making a first party is pretty hard. I finally managed it just a couple weeks ago and spent the whole night making extensive use of my own plugin (which makes blueberry waffles in Python), but failed to produce a second party.

Of course, maybe that was just a fluke, but I can't be sure unless I can find an easier way to keep the first parties going. Maybe I should move to Iceland, I hear they're [big on parties there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_Iceland). Probably because it's always Friday.